# How to add custom Ansible connection plugin for this playbook only?

Tags: plugins, ansible

I want to write a custom connection plugin for Ansible. I only want to use it for one particular playbook. I want to distribute it with that playbook. (Same git repo.)

[The docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_locally.html#adding-standalone-local-plugins-for-selected-playbooks-or-a-single-role) say:

> To use a standalone plugin only in a selected playbook or playbooks, store the plugin in a subdirectory for the correct `plugin_type` (for example, `callback_plugins` or `inventory_plugins`) in the directory that contains the playbooks. These directories must use the _plugins suffix. For a full list of plugin types, see [Working with plugins.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/plugins.html#working-with-plugins)

That "working with plugins" page says:

> You can extend Ansible to support other transports (such as SNMP or message bus) by dropping a custom plugin into the `connection_plugins` directory.

Let's assume my playbook is at `./playbook.yaml`.
These docs sound like it's as simple as saving my file as `./connection_plugins/my_connector.py`:

```
mkdir connection_plugins
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible-collections/community.aws/e80bf933412ea5c7ab2a94af945170cb2ebd900f/plugins/connection/aws_ssm.py | sed -e 's/aws_ssm/my_connector/g' > connection_plugins/my_connector.py
```

So now my directory looks like

- `./playbook.yaml`
- `./connection_plugins/my_connector.py`

As per [the connection plugins docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection.html), I should be able to list all connection plugins with:

```
ansible-doc -t connection -l
```

This shows several plugins, but none of them are `my_connector`.
I assume this means I did not put my custom connector plugin into the correct location. But I believe I followed the documentation. So I don't know why it didn't work.

What is the correct location for a custom connector plugin for be used only for a nearby playbook?
Should `ansible-doc -t connection -l` show locally installed plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ansible-doc` does not call a playbook, so by default it doesn't have a place to load playbook-adjacent plugins from. As with most ansible commands that do not work with playbooks, it supports a `--playbook-dir` argument that you can use to specify the path for loading these plugins.

Ultimately, though, the best way to test if you've put the plugin in the correct location is to attempt to use it in your playbook. If it works, you have; if it doesn't, it doesn't really matter whether `ansible-doc` listed it.